# How OpenAM verify SAML response coming from IDP

Tags: saml, openam

is OpenAM depends on the public key of the registered IDP to versify the SAML response

or depends also on the hashing algorithm in the SAML response from IDP
    like Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"

Note OpenAM version :13.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenAM, acting as SAML SP, uses the public key enclosed in the KeyInfo element of the IdP meta data to verify the signature of the SAML response. It uses the signature algorithm chosen by the IdP, however it must be a supported signature algorithm.

Comment: how i know if OpenAM supports specific algorithm coming from IDP.
is there is a way to force idp to use spcifc hashing algorithm like RSA-SHA265 instead of RSA-SHA1 @Bernhard Thalmayr

Comment: OpenAM will offer the signature algorithms provided by the library being used, here  http://santuario.apache.org/. Newer versions of ForgeRock Access Management configure santuario to remove weak/banned algorithms like SHA1 for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

In upcoming versions of AM, AM will (partially) implement the [algsupport spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-metadata-algsupport-cd-01.pdf), and will take into account remote entity provider's metadata when signing SAML documents.

This means that as a hosted entity provider, AM will check the remote entity provider's preferred signing and digest methods, and will use the first algorithm that satisfies the key type and key size requirements.

This work has been completed as part of [OPENAM-11266](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-11266).